# Why do Office 2016 context menu strings in the registry sometimes reference nonexistent DLLs?

Tags: shell, command, registry, ms-office

Normally the context menu display string for a command verb is contained in the default value of `HKCR\[class]\Shell\[verb]`. For example, the default value of `HKCR\Word.Document.12\Shell\Open` is usually '&Open', which is the menu string.

But in some Win10 installations of Office 2016, the menu string is different. Instead of '&Open', it looks like this:

@C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\Office16\oregres.dll,-3

Fine, this is a reference to the string with resource ID 3 in oregres.dll.
But there's a problem: On a 64-bit machine, oregres.dll doesn't exist in that folder; instead it's under ProgramFilesCommonX64 (X64 instead of X86).

Sure, I can change 'X86' to 'X64' and try again if the library load fails, but I'd like to know why this is happening before I do something as kludgy as that.

Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the inside story as to why this clearly out-of-place string has littered Office 2016, but, in addition to Word 2016's, you will find the same nonsense among Outlook 2016's entries within 64-bit Spyware 10's proprietary trash heap — I mean, Registry:

[Outlook 2016 Excel Previewer Not Working](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-excel-previewer-not-working/390ed8b1-feba-4ac6-b882-aafa4cfade9a)

['This file cannot be previewed, because there is no previewer installed for it' Error When You Preview Excel Workbooks in Outlook 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3100511)

If your reasonable kludge does not yield the proper string (and even if it does and the string could just as easily be hard-coded with no consequence), I should stick with typing it in.